# Why os.chdir() cant change dir in this case?

Tags: python, operating-system

----input

```
print(os.getcwd(), '\n')
print(os.listdir(), '\n')

Gui_path = '/Gui'

os.chdir(Gui_path)
```

----output

C:\Users\vhass\Documents\Coding Projects\The vault

C:\Users\vhass\Documents\Coding Projects\The vault

['application.py', 'crypto.py', 'encrypting.py', 'genaccount.py', 'Gui', 'Home.py', 'icons', 'login.py', 'main.py', 'Pics', 'test.py', 'Usernamepass.py', '**pycache**']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vhass\Documents\Coding Projects\The vault\login.py", line 19, in 
    os.chdir(Gui_path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '/Gui'

note ****
The path in this project is not static and might be changed based on user preference, so I can not use the full path.

Comment: The note explains the problem -- you can't use the full path. Yet you did. "/Gui" is a full path -- that's what the leading slash means,

Comment: `"Why os.chdir() cant change dir in this case?"` The error clearly says **why** it can't change dir, because it can't find it.

Comment: how it can't while os.listdir() clearly shows Gui in the directory? check out my output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're providing a full path and not a relative one. `os.chdir('/Gui')` is trying to go to your root directory (`/`) and look for a folder `Gui` there.

I think what you're trying to do is look for the folder `Gui` relative to the current directory. Try something like

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/tyler/tmp/stackoverflow'
>>> os.listdir()
['a', 'f', 'Gui', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b']
>>> os.chdir(os.getcwd() + '/Gui') # <- This is the important line
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/tyler/tmp/stackoverflow/Gui'
>>> os.listdir()
['HELLO']
>>>
```

See how we're doing a string join of `os.getcwd() + '/Gui'` rather than just `'/Gui'`? That ensures we're looking within the directory that we're currenly in.

You should also take a look at the stdlib [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for other helpful primitives, and to ensure that your code handles weird file system edge cases.